# Creating an SQLite table only if it doesn't already exist

Tags: php, sqlite

I need my PHP app to be able to create an SQLite table but only if it doesn't already exist. How should I go about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create table in SQLite only if it doesn't exist already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098008/create-table-in-sqlite-only-if-it-doesnt-exist-already)

Comment: you can do as shown ;) [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HyfK.png) ;use the sql statement CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS and then specify column name their types

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <name> (
  /* definition */
)
```

Which is supported by SQLite (http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#create-table-stmt)

Comment: Just tried it. I get: Warning: SQLiteDatabase::queryExec() [sqlitedatabase.queryexec]: near "NOT". It's a PHP app.

Comment: The version is 3.6.20. Here's the code: $query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (content TEXT, author TEXT)";

$db->queryExec($query, $error) or die($error);

Comment: Works like a charm for me:
sqlite> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (content TEXT, author TEXT);
sqlite> .tables
messages

Comment: Still get the warning. I'm going to use the `@` operator before the queryExec for the time being.

Comment: @MPelletier: The version is is 3.6.20.

Comment: @Emanuil: You need to use "new SQLite3" not "new SQLiteDatabase"

Answer (score 6):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`IF NOT EXISTS`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).