# database "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" syntax error

Tags: android, database

> My code contains a database class.While running it shows an error regarding with the CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statement.please the give me the solution to correct the  error.

clasdbOpenHelper.java

```
package example.events1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class classdbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_DESC = "countdesc";
    public static final String KEY_DATE = "countdate";
    public static final String KEY_EVENT = "countevent";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME= "countdb";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "countable";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    public classdbOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
                + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_DESC + " TEXT, " + KEY_DATE + " TEXT, " + KEY_EVENT + " TEXT  )";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXITS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }


    public Cursor fetchAllEvents() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_DESC, KEY_DATE, KEY_EVENT },
        null, null, null, null, null );
        if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
   }

    public Cursor fetchEventByName(String inputText,String datevalue ) throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor mCursor = null;
        if (inputText == null || inputText.length () == 0) {
        mCursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_DESC, KEY_DATE, KEY_EVENT },
        null, null, null, null, null);
        }
        else {
            mCursor  =  db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM countable WHERE countdesc = ? AND countdate = ?", new String[] {inputText,datevalue});           
        }

        if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
   }

    public void delete(long id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id )});
        db.close();
    }
}
```

> logcat

```
08-20 04:32:26.411: E/SQLiteLog(839): (1) near "EXISTScountable": syntax error
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{example.events1/example.events1.Getclicker}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "EXISTScountable": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTScountable(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, countdesc TEXT, countdate TEXT, countevent TEXT  )
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "EXISTScountable": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTScountable(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, countdesc TEXT, countdate TEXT, countevent TEXT  )
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at example.events1.classdbOpenHelper.onCreate(classdbOpenHelper.java:31)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:188)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at example.events1.classdbOpenHelper.fetchEventByName(classdbOpenHelper.java:57)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at example.events1.Getclicker.onCreate(Getclicker.java:36)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-20 04:32:26.681: E/AndroidRuntime(839):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please try the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098008/sqlite-create-table-if-doesnt-exist

Answer (score 10):

give space after EXISTS like this

```
String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE + "("
            + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_DESC + " TEXT, " + KEY_DATE + " TEXT, " + KEY_EVENT + " TEXT  )";
```

Answer (score 4):

you have no space between `EXISTS` and table name, `countable` in your case.