# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS statement in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a WPF application where I access a SQLite database via ADO.NET (http://adodotnetsqlite.sourceforge.net/). So far everything works fine, but when I try to execute the following SQL:

```
 sqlite_cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notes (id integer primary key, text varchar(100));";
 sqlite_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I get the following exception:

```
An exception of type 'Finisar.SQLite.SQLiteException' occurred in SQLite.NET.dll but was not handled in user code.
Additional information: near "NOT": syntax error
```

When I remove the `IF NOT EXISTS` part it works fine, but I want to create the table only if it is not already there. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Potentially related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1601151/23902?  Oddly, though, that question says that SQLite 3.3+ supports `IF NOT EXISTS`...

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716443/creating-an-sqlite-table-only-if-it-doesnt-already-exist which runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1601151/23902) has some answers which may be helpful.  From that question, however, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5205530/23902) suggests that SQLite 3.3 and above support `IF NOT EXISTS`.

Based on that question's answers, you could try selecting the COUNT of tables named 'notes' using this (slightly modified) query:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='notes';`

You can then test the result of that query.  If there were 0 results, create the table.  Otherwise, don't create the table.